# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions

I have file with unittest named: test.py

My code:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def myTest(self):
        a = 1
        self.assertEqual(a, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I press F5, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mariusz/Pulpit/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/home/mariusz/Pulpit/unittest.py", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestCase'
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have a local file named `unittest.py` that is being imported instead:

```
/home/mariusz/Pulpit/unittest.py
```

Rename that file or remove it altogether. Make sure you remove any corresponding `unittest.pyc` file in the same folder if it is there.

The file is masking the standard library package.

Answer (score 1):

Your script named unittest.py is replacing the module file.
Rename your unittest.py script to something else.

Comment: Your answer is just a copy of the accepted answer above from more than five years ago.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one of the dependency was not there.

```
import os
from some_package import some_module
```

the some_module was not there in python(python couldn't import it). Once I commented the import statement python started discovering my test cases.

```
python -m unittest tests.test_my_own_module
```