# I study Python on Windows ,random.shuffle(), a function was be readed as a atrribute,what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[This is the Picture with BUGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztuWG.png) It is ok on Python IDLE, but wrong on commandLine, is there anything wrong? Python version 3.6.4, win10 64bit, thanks for you to guide me, I am new with Python, the example is on the book PYTHON FOR KIDS, Jason Briggs

Comment: Put a [mcve], **in text form**, in the question itself. Also don't name your scripts after existing modules...

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe, it's solved

Answer (score 1):

Change the file name from random.py to studyrandom.py, filename is same to the module, so it is wrong

Comment: I'd just delete the question, there are loads of dupes already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893504/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-testcase